# Can we configure the expiry date of FirebaseToken?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

The access token which is returned after hitting 'oauth/token' expires after 3600 secs (1 hour).

I understand as per the docs that this is the max time given to a user and after that the token has to be refreshed.

My question is is there a way to decrease this expiry time? I mean If we want a specific user to access an application for 30 mins only. So, how is that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to decrease this expiry time?

No, the token is configured by Firebase Authentication, and there is no mechanism provided to change that.  You can instead write your own code to check the expiration on the token and refuse to accept it based on your own logic.